# Cannot get regional keyboard on windows phone emulator 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

I set language to french and keyboard to french and restarted the emulator, still the separator for number stays "." instead of "," whereas on physical device I have ",".

Is the emulator bugged on that point ?

Answer (score 1):

You should switch the Regional format to French.

Comment: That's what I did so my question :) on my physical device it works but not on emulator even the wp8 emulator

Comment: Did you set French in all three places? (Region format, Display language and Keyboard). I don't understadn where exactly do you expect to see ",". But if I set InputScope for textBox to 'CurrencyAmount' I see "." as a separator. Looks like this is a bug.